# Как создать createContext в ReacJS TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Создаю провайдер в котором хочу подключить Апи сервис и потом в любом месте я мог вызвать нужный метод через  useContext.
В чистом EcmaScript все работает отлично, но в TypeScript  не работает.

```
import { createContext } from 'react'
import { ApiService, IService } from '../services/ApiService'

export const ApiSerivceContext = createContext()

export const ApiServiceProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {

    const api = new ApiService()

    return (
        <ApiSerivceContext.Provider value={api}>
            {children}
        </ApiSerivceContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Вот так я создаю контекст, но когда вызываю его в файле App.js контекст пустой. C reducer  понятно как делать. Нужно сделать type, потом  initialState. но как быть с сервисом, где методы и параметры будут увеличиваться?

Comment: как ты его вызываешь?

Comment: const apiContext = useContext(ApiSerivceContext)
Вот такъ

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createContext } from 'react'
import { ApiService, IService } from '../services/ApiService'

export const ApiSerivceContext = createContext<ApiService | null>(null)

export const ApiServiceProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {

    const api = new ApiService()

    return (
        <ApiSerivceContext.Provider value={api}>
            {children}
        </ApiSerivceContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

если правильно понял возможно динамически указать например как интерфейс и этот интерфейс можно применить к обекту с бесконечным количеством ключей естественно если тип совпадает

```
interface IAp {
[key:type]:type
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается нужно было вот таким образом передать класс.

```
import { createContext } from 'react'
import { ApiService, IService } from '../services/ApiService'

export const ApiSerivceContext = createContext<IService>(new ApiService() )

export const ApiServiceProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {

    const api = new ApiService()

    return (
        <ApiSerivceContext.Provider value={api}>
            {children}
        </ApiSerivceContext.Provider>
    )
}
```